# Añadir espacios de tabulacion en CKEditor 5

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Estoy tratando de añadir a CKEitor 5 la funcionalidad del boton TAB, es decir, agregar 4 espacios al precionar el tabulador.

buscando lo unico que encontre fue el codigo que ven aqui abajo

```js
ClassicEditor
    .create(document.querySelector('#editor'))
    .then(editor => {
       editor.editing.view.document.on( 'keydown', function(e){

              if ( e.keyCode == 9 ) {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  this.value+="    ";
              }
       });
       myEditor = editor;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/11.2.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
<textarea id="editor"></textarea>
```

No estando conforme, ya que me cambia el focus,  probe lo siguiente, tratando de tomar el objeto `editor` (que en fin de cuentas es el editor creado por la libreria)

```js
ClassicEditor
    .create(document.querySelector('#editor'))
    .then(editor => {
       $(editor).on( 'keydown', function(e){
              if ( e.keyCode == 9 ) {
                  console.log( 'AAAAAA!!' );
                  e.preventDefault();
                  this.value += "    ";
              }
       });
                  
       myEditor = editor;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/11.2.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
<textarea id="editor"></textarea>
```

pero como ven, al precionar el TAB sigue cambiando el focus.

otro tentativo fue el siguiente, tratando de tomarlo gracias a las clases que utiliza CKEditor (clases tomadas de la ventana de desarrollo):

```js
ClassicEditor
    .create(document.querySelector('#editor'))
    .then(editor => {
       $(".ck.ck-content.ck-editor__editable.ck-rounded-corners.ck-blurred.ck-editor__editable_inline").on( 'keydown', function(e){

              if ( e.keyCode == 9 ) {
                  editor.setData(editor.getData()+"    ");
                  e.preventDefault();
              }
       });
       myEditor = editor;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/11.2.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
<textarea id="editor"></textarea>
```

en este caso directamente no hace nada mientras que si trato de alcanzar el textarea :

```js
ClassicEditor
    .create(document.querySelector('#editor'))
    .then(editor => {
       $("#editor").on( 'keydown', function(e){

              if ( e.keyCode == 9 ) {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  this.value+="    ";
              }
       });
                   
       myEditor = editor;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/11.2.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
<textarea id="editor"></textarea>
```

me sigue cambiando el focus.

alguien tendria alguna idea de como podria hacer ?

Comment: Has probado con este addon? https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/tab

Comment: @kosmosan es para la version 4 :( que no me funciona al interno de SharePoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontre la solucion!

hay que utilizar la propriedad `.keystrokes.set()` a la cual hay que pasar como parametro :`keyName` y `callback` en mi caso : `editor.keystrokes.set("tab", (data, cancel) => {...})`.

para agregar el texto hay que utilizar el metodo `change` del modelo : `editor.model.change ( writer => {...})`
ahi instanciamos un writer, y le decimos que queremos añadir como testo plano `'    '`, eso se hace de la siguiente manera : `writer.insertText("    ", editor.model.document.selection.getFirstPosition())`
ahi lo que estamos haciendo es :

1. le decimos que insertar en este caso `'    '` (4 espacios)
2. donde lo queremos insertar ? en este caso agarramos nuevamente el modelo, y le decimos que tome la primera posision de la seleccion que hemos echo al interno del documento.

y el `cancel()` toma la funcion de `e.preventDefault`, es este caso es nativo osea que evita conflictos con otras partes de codigo.

**PD: para probar el codigo escribir algo al interno del documento, en caso contrario el puntador queda al inicio aunque añada la indentacion**

```js
ClassicEditor
      .create(document.querySelector('#editor'))
      .then(editor => {
          editor.keystrokes.set( 'Tab', ( data, cancel ) => {
             editor.model.change( writer => {
                  writer.insertText("    ", editor.model.document.selection.getFirstPosition()) 
             });
             cancel();
           });
        myEditor = editor;
     })
     .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/11.2.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
<textarea id="editor"></textarea>
```

espero que sea de ayuda para alguien mas !